# How to find out if there is anymore words after a full stop?

Tags: php, html, text, frontend, laravel-8

I have some text's stored in the database and while I show them in the frontend I place the words before each full-stop within a li tag.

```
<ol><li> {!! str_replace(".","</li><li>", $sscat->inclusion) !!} </li></ol>
```

Everything is working fine except when the text has a full-stop at the very end, it ends up showing an empty numbering.
For example, if I have "aaaaaa.Something Something." the output will be like-

1. aaaaaa
2. Something Something
3. 

So What can I do to prevent that empty list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a trailing `.` in the last list item, you can use `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace` to avoid replacing that one if it's present.

```
preg_replace("/\.(?!$)/", "</li><li>", $sscat->inclusion)
```

If you *don't* want to show it, aynber's answer looks good to me, but if you'd rather not use a loop, you can also just trim it off before doing the replacements.

```
str_replace(".","</li><li>", rtrim($sscat->inclusion, '.'))
```

Another possibility you might want to consider is modifying the model to handle trailing `.`s in the inclusion [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor), so you won't have to do this again if you have other templates that use that property.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of replacing, what I'd do is [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) the string into an array, [filter out empty values](https://www.php.net/array_filter), then iterate through the results

```
<ol>
@foreach(array_filter(explode('.', $sscat->inclusion)) as $item) 
    <li>{!! $item !!}</li>
@endforeach
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of the other answer, just explode, filter and implode:

```
<ol><li>{!! implode("</li><li>", array_filter(explode(".", $sscat->inclusion))) !!}</li></ol>
```